# How to setup Brother HL-2135W over wifi under Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, router, drivers, printer

First of all I have to tell that I am aware my whole question might be partly off-topic here as well as it would have been on AU (therefore I did not post there, SU seems to be the appropriate place for that) but please try to help.

**My problem:**

Everything went fine until a non-planned power loss. After the blackout the router of my ISP started to serve IPs via DHCP from an other subnet than the previous, so I would like to reconfigure my printer accordingly.

(Note: now I made a factory reset on the printer - as shown below -, therefore I am neither able to modify the previous settings, nor able to configure again due to the problems described below.)

**What I did in order to solve the issue:**

1. Tried to reconfigure the printer under Windows 10 post-Anniversary Update with the [newest driver suite available](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=hl2135w_us_eu_as&os=10013#SelectLanguageType-11_0_1) to reach wifi functionality. Unfortunately during install the driver exits with INI file error message. (I had this problem before the Win 10 compatible drivers released, but in that case an updated driver or a factory reset helped - I do not know exactly it was a long ago).
2. Made a factory reset on 2135W then went to #1, still no luck.
3. According to the user manual I have re-enabled wifi and printed network configuration page. IP address, DNS and so shows 0.0.0.0 as it's value. The Windows drivers still not working.
4. I have noticed a new SSID appeared related to the printer called SETUP. Since I did not manage to configure proper ad-hoc wifi network under W10 I just tried it with Ubuntu 16.04, and it worked! I have successfully connected to it via [this guide](http://pc1mh-weblog.blogspot.hu/2015/03/brother-hl-2135w-on-ubuntu-via-secure.html) but when I try to change IP, GW and subnet mask to the correct values it becomes unavailable, so I cannot continue configuration.

What should I do next?

Thanks

Comment: This is unclear what you are working on. Your title states setting up a printer and the body of your post discusses configuring a router. Please [edit] your question to be more clear which device you are working on.

Comment: @CharlieRB You are absolutely right! Sorry for the confusing discussion of the topic. I hope I made it a bit more clear.